# Need unit tested application in asp .net webforms

Tags: unit-testing, webforms, nunit

Hi one of my client needs unit tested application in asp .net webforms. But I have no Idea about how to start or unit tested applicaton/MVC. I would like to know how to create unit tested application in webforms. Any example, video, tutorial will be helpfull.

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the following things:

1. Start asking your client and yourself what it is you want to achieve? Merely unit testing for no other reason than saying you are unit testing is not a worthy goal to pursue.
2. Read some introductory book like [The Art Of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/) to make yourself familiar with unit testing.
3. Consider reading [this ASP.NET MVC book](http://www.apress.com/9781430242369) because it takes you through all layers of an ASP.NET MVC app while applying unit testing at each of those layers (with really good examples).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with point 1 of meilke's answer. Adding unit testing to an existing application can be a lot of work and without a good reason, it's unlikely a customer will want to pay for it. It is possible however to use a request to add or remove functionality as an opportunity to get started. For example, if you have a task to remove some existing functionality then putting a set of unit tests in place to verify the existing behaviour of the application can save headaches later on. Think of it like putting scaffolding in place before doing construction work.

It's not clear from your question but if it's ASP.NET WebForms as distinct from ASP.NET MVC that you are looking to unit test, I would recommend looking into the [Model View Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) design pattern. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14642/Model-View-Presenter-with-ASP-NET) and [here](http://www.contentedcoder.com/2012/04/mvp-design-pattern-survival-kit.html) are a couple of articles that should help.